# Python Can this script be multithreaded?

Tags: python, multithreading, tornado

It would be great if someone could help me with multi-threading this script and write the output to a text file. 
I am really new at coding, so please help me out.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from tornado import ioloop, httpclient
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser
import requests
import urllib2
import socket
import sys

def handle_request(response):
    print response.code

global i

i = 0
i -= 1
if i == 0:
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
for url in open('urls.txt'):
    try:
        br = Browser()
        br.set_handle_robots(False)
        res = br.open(url, None, 2.5)
        data = res.get_data()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
        title = soup.find('title')
        if soup.title != None:
            print url, title.renderContents(), '\n'
        i += 1
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print "Oops, timed out?", '\n'
    except socket.error,e:
        print "Oops, timed out?", '\n'
    except socket.timeout:
        print "Oops, timed out?", '\n'
print 'Processing of list completed, Cheers!!'
sys.exit()
try:
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()
```

I am trying to grep the HTTP title of a list of hosts.

Comment: What did you try? :)

Comment: "I am new to coding" - You probably don't want to dive into multithreading quite yet then

Comment: You just need to loop over your urls because you are using an asynchronous request which will not block your program. You should register a callback which will be called if the response becomes availible `http_client.fetch(url, request_callback_handler)`.

Comment: @muddyfish i have around 4000 ips to grep the title :/

Comment: @wenzul i wish i understand you :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea you have already implemented is [an non-blocking HTTP client.](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/httpclient.html)

```
def handle_request(response):
    if response.error:
        print "Error:", response.error
    else:
        print response.body

for url in ["http://google.com", "http://twitter.com"]:
    http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
    http_client.fetch(url, handle_request)
```

You could loop over your urls and the callback will be called as soon the respone for a specific url becomes availible.

I wouldn't mix up mechanize, ioloop,... if not necessary.

---

Apart from that, I recommend [grequests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/grequests/0.2.0). It is a lightweight tool which satisfies your requirements.

```
import grequests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://www.python.org/']

rs = (grequests.get(u) for u in urls)
res = grequests.map(rs)

for r in res:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    print "%s: %s" % (r.url, soup.title.text)
```

Comment: could you tell me how i can apply that in my code. ? I want to speed it up, i have around 4000+ hosts to scan.

Comment: i managed to get it that much by googling and rips from scripts.

my goal is to grab the HTTP title of a list of ip's (4000+ hosts) and output it to a file.

Comment: @iqzer0 Yes the source code seems to be a mix of google results. You have to keep some structure in your source code and mind.

Comment: Your requests are  'non-blocking' meaning its not consuming any CPU when its not busy,since you are using `AsyncHTTPClient` which is an asynchronous http client. This means performance should be fine for 4000+ hosts. Before you do something see what synchronous/asynchronous is. It can be really dangerous if you do not understand what you are doing

Comment: It can be really dangerous means that you could become the status of an DOS attacker. So take care.

Comment: thanks for the info @wenzul and DeepankarBajpey , i wouldn't want to DoS the hosts :/
could you be kind enough to tell me how the final output should be ?